# Vim error when creating folder

Tags: vim

I'm not exactly sure how to reproduce the problem. I get an error when I try to create a folder after `:Explore` and `d`.

[image]

The folder actually gets created but I need to close and reopen the tab to view it.

However, this tends to happen fairly frequently but won't happen say if I try to make a folder immediately after I boot up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create the folder if you use the `:!mkdir folder_name` command? Perhaps the process doesn't have enough permissions directly?

Answer (score 2):

First, try using the latest version of *netrw* from [DrChip's website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW). If the problem persists, try to make it reproducible (or at least ensure that no other settings cause this by temporarily disabling all other plugins and .vimrc configuration), and submit this problem to the plugin's author (contact info is in the help file).

Comment: Also, make sure a reasonably recent version of Vim is installed. (7.2.* and lower are outdated.)